# flat database object vs object with relation properties - naming convention

Tags: c#, sqlkata

I am in a struggle for naming my objects. I will start with an example.

I have a customer table in de the database. A object (short) version would look like this

```
public class CustomerModel

{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string CustomerGroup { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the customer has a AddressID, which indicates that it has a relation to a address.

So I also wanted a second object for the customer that contains the Address object. Something like:

```
public class CustomerAddressModel : CustomerModel
    {
        public int AddressID => Address.AddressID;

        [Ignore]
        public AddressModel Address { get; set; }
    }
```

(p.s. I think I broke the inheritance in this example.)

The second object is called its base model + its child/relation model. Customer and Address, CustomerAddressModel. Personally I am not happy with this naming convention that I am using cause if the model had 10 relations, it would become a problem.

We use the 'Model' to indicate that its a database object and Dto for.. well data transfere. (and some more conventions)

What could be a good naming convention for objects that includes the relationship object(s) which gives the difference between a flat object.

p.s. using sqlkata if that gives any meaning.

Comment: Let's take a step back for a second. Why do you feel like you need a second model rather than putting the Address property on CustomerModel ? It seems like a needless complexity to me.

Comment: So CustomerAddressModel is effectively a DTO? 

If I understand what you are saying, then you would be better mapping the domain classes to actual DTOs, and not having DTOs inherit from domain classes.  The simplest naming convention would be to use Dto as a suffix.

Comment: @Luke mostly thinking about loops. If you loop multiple customers, change the relations object, but forget to change the flat property. Than the insert/update would be incorrect. I created the relation object so the customer.AdressID links to the customer.Address.AddressID. So its value is locked in one place. But maybe you are right that i am making it more complex than needed and keep it as a Dto

Comment: I agree that this is an unwanted complexity, but if you insist you can name it `CustomerWithAddress` instead of `CustomerAddress`